# Change/set default folder for Microsoft print to PDF?

Tags: pdf, printer, print-to-pdf

My "Microsoft Print to PDF printer" prints into desktop folder by default.
How can I change it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In *Printers and Scanners*, click on the printer and click *Manage*. Click *Printer properties*, then click *Ports*. If it is not set to *`PORTPROMPT:`*, try setting it to that so that it will ask you where you want to save the file. If that doesn't work, what port is it pointing to?